# How do i make a "sanity" bar?

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to make a value stored in the player that starts at 100 and decrements until equal to 0, and once equal to 0, the player dies.

```
local players = game:GetService("Players")
local plr = players.LocalPlayer.Character
local sanity = plr.Sanity.Value
local hum = plr:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")

while sanity > 0 do
    if sanity == 0 then
        hum.Health = 0
    end
    wait(0.05)
    sanity -= 1
    print(sanity)
end
```

The problem is that even though the value exists, it is not decrementing it or printing the new value.

I don't know where do start so I haven't tried much, It's supposed to decrement the value every second and kill the player once the value == 0

edit: i found a different way to do it that works perfectly fine

Comment: Lua does not have the `-=` operator, so you have to do `x = x - 1`. Surely you are getting a syntax error pointing at this line?

Comment: @vitiral Roblox's implementation of Lua ("Luau") does support the `-=` and similar operators.

Comment: Lacking context or Roblox experience, but it seems that the local variable `sanity` will just be a number that is no longer connected to the player after you read it. Maybe you would be able to do `plr.Sanity.Value = sanity` or something similar after changing it.

Comment: it is true that `plr.Sanity.Value` would **not** change from this code, but it doesn't make sense that the local `sanity` wouldn't change. I'm wondering if this isn't a faithful reproduction and they are actually checking `plr.Sanity.Value` when they say (here) that they are looking at the local variable.

Comment: It occurred to me that it's possible `Sanity.Value` is another type (table or userdata) and luau allows you to override the `-=` metaevent. In that case this may be detecting a bug with the metaevent they've implemented, but this is a lot of guesswork.